# Query Dates From SQLServer in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am building a web application that is going to show the upcoming birthdays of a list of people stored in a SQL Server 2008 DB. I can't figure out how to query all records in the DB that are within 30 days of today's date.

Here's what I have so far:

```
using (HumanResourcesDB db = newH umanResourcesDB(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HumanResourcesDB"].ConnectionString))
            {
                DateTime todaysDate = DateTime.Now;

                List<Employee> record =
                (from tab in db.Employees
                 where tab.Birthday between DateTime.Now and todaysDate.AddDays(30) 
                 select tab).ToList();
                this.grdBirthdays.DataSource = record;
                this.grdBirthdays.DataBind();
            }
```

of course the "between" and "and" don't work that's what I need filled in. I've searched the net for a little while to no avail. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a greater than and less than

```
using (HumanResourcesDB db = newHumanResourcesDB(ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["HumanResourcesDB"].ConnectionString))
{
    List<Employee> record = (from tab in db.Employees
     where tab.Birthday >= DateTime.Today
     && tab.Birthday < DateTime.Today.AddDays(31)
     select tab).ToList();

    this.grdBirthdays.DataSource = record;

    this.grdBirthdays.DataBind();
}
```

Also I should mention that I have used DateTime.Today rather than DateTime.Now because today represents the start of the day as 00:00:00.000. If someones birthday is set to whatever today is at 00:00:00.000 and you have used DateTime.Now (let's assume it's 8:00 in the morning). There birthday will not be included in this range because it is considered before "now".

Comment: Then you understand that the end of the range should probably be `< AddDays(31)` not `<= AddDays(30)` - if someone's birthday is not set to midnight on the last day, they'll get excluded for the same reason.

Comment: I tried that earlier it gives a few errors.
"The type or namespace name 'AND' could not be found"
"A local variable named 'tab' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'tab', which is already used in a 'child'scope to denote something else"

Comment: @bromanguy Try to uncapitlize(spelling?) the AND make it lower case.

Comment: @JamesHay same error. Am I missing a library referenece or something?

Comment: Well I did copy and paste but then I deleted everything on that line after "where tab.Birthday". From there my SQL typing instinct kicked in and the rest is history.

Comment: Sorry it's &&, not sure what I'm up to.